# What's the most efficient algorithm to determine the relative ordering of an unknown set of values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, algorithmic-game-theory

This comes from [a question on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/151507/5398).

> The background is, there's a mall level.  Vlad the organized crime
>   boss wants $50,000 worth of mall property destroyed.  Your task is to
>   shoot and blow stuff up until that happens.
>
> There are 12 stores in the mall, and you have 3 grenades.  After you
>   blow up the first three stores, if you haven't ruined $50,000 worth of
>   stuff in three explosions, you switch to your rifle and shatter store
>   windows until you reach that limit.  Then you leave.

Good wholesome fun.

The absolute value of the stores is unknown, but I'm interested in determining the *relative* value - obviously, I want to use my three grenades where they'll do the most good.  As I see it, I have a set of 12 unknown variables, representing the value of each of the individual stores:

$ {O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z} $

and one constant $C$, representing the value of windows.

I know which three stores I've destroyed and I can count how many windows I need to shoot to give me a Mission Accomplished.

Knowing only those two pieces of information, it should be possible through experimentation to order the unknown set.  Let's say on trial #1 I destroy stores X,Y,Z and it takes me 4 windows to reach $50k.  On trial #2, I destroy stores W,Y,Z and it takes 3 windows.

If $X + Y + Z + 4C = W + Y + Z + 3C$, then we can say that $W > X$.

**What's the most efficient way to run this algorithm to conclusion for all 12 stores?  Each trial takes about 6 minutes and I don't want to duplicate effort.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good mathematical solution:

Run 12 trials, starting with $O+P+Q$, then $P+Q+R$, then $Q+R+S$, etc., and for each one record the number of windows as a negative integer.  For example,
$$\begin{align}O+P+Q&=-w_1\\
P+Q+R&=-w_2\\
Q+R+S&=-w_3\\
\vdots\\
X+Y+Z&=-w_{10}\\
Y+Z+O&=-w_{11}\\
Z+O+P&=-w_{12}\end{align}$$

This gives you an almost-tridiagonal matrix problem:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
&&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}O\\P\\Q\\R\\S\\T\\U\\V\\W\\X\\Y\\Z\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}-w_1\\-w_2\\-w_3\\\vdots\\-w_{10}\\-w_{11}\\-w_{12}\end{array}\right],$$
which you can either use your favorite package to solve, or calculate the actual inverse ahead of time if you'll be doing this a lot of times.

This will give you negative values for each store, and the largest (i.e., least negative) ones are the highest values.

I think it's not possible to know all the stores' values in fewer than 12 tests.  It may be possible to determine the 3 largest values in fewer than 12 tests, but I don't have such an algorithm handy.